# Current Datatype held by UNION in C

Tags: c

How to find which data is currently union variable is holding out of the many fields present in the union without keeping extra variable to track it.

Comment: Why can't you use an extra variable?

Comment: we can use it,but i want know is there any way to do it without using extra variable.

Comment: That doesn't make for a good StackOverflow question, if you're just curious.

Comment: The question makes no sense. Either you can analyze the raw contents of the memory occupied by the union and tell datatypes apart, or you can't. If you can, then this identifier part should be turned into a type selector and hoisted out of the union.

Comment: You can't. That information is not saved anywhere.

Comment: Thanks kuroi neko !!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this. All of the variables are holding some or all of the same data in memory, whether that data is meaningful or not.